# No org-babel-execute function for js!

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-babel

I'm using org-mode in Spacemacs and have this code block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC js :var payload=access-token-payload
let parsedPayload = JSON.parse(access-token-payload);
return parsedPayload.access_token;
#+END_SRC
```

Expected behavior:
The code executes when I press `C-c` `C-c`

Actual behavior:
I get an error saying `No org-babel-execute function for js!`. This should be supported since org-babel is present. I code a lot of Node and Javascript applications so Node is in my path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable evaluation of js code.  "Section 16.9" of org manual states:

> By default, only 'emacs-lisp' is enabled for evaluation.  To enable
> or disable other languages, customize the `org-babel-load-languages'
> variable either through the Emacs customization interface, or by adding
> code to the init file as shown next:

> In this example, evaluation is disabled for 'emacs-lisp', and enabled
> for 'R'.

> ```
> (org-babel-do-load-languages
> ```

```
  'org-babel-load-languages
  '((emacs-lisp . nil)
    (R . t)))
```

The provided example is not totally clear IMHO but that works.
Another way to enable a language is to `require` the org babel module for the language, eg here:

```
M-: (require 'ob-js)
```

Comment: This is strange because I was using `bash`, `python` and `org` code blocks without any issue, out of the box. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot find `ob-js` in *melpa* or *melpa-stable*. Where is `ob-js` being maintained?

Comment: It is included in org! org-9.4.6.tar contains -rw-r--r--    elpa/elpa       7397 org-9.4.6/ob-js.el